# How can I disable `ApplePressAndHoldEnabled` for a specific application (repeat keys instead of showing an accent menu)?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 Community Edition in Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.5.

I already know about the global `ApplePressAndHoldEnabled` fix:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

But I want to disable it only for IntelliJ IDEA, and none of these commands work when using the "IdeaVim" plugin with Scala (With restarting IDEA):

```
defaults write com.jetbrains.intellij.ce ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
defaults write com.jetbrains.intellij ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
defaults write com.jetbrains.AppCode ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Or any of the other commands listed [here](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5466537).

**How do you disable `ApplePressAndHoldEnabled` for a specific application?**

Comment: were you able to solve this problem by any chance? This drives me crazy and none of the default domains work

Comment: See the canonical, complete solution to this problem, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70911250/14193

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the canonical, complete solution to this problem:

## Settings for `ApplePressAndHoldEnabled`:

The boolean values of the `ApplePressAndHoldEnabled` Mac OS `defaults` correspond to the following settings:

- `true` => `show-character-accents-menu`: Holding a keyboard key down will bring up a character modification menu like so:
  [image: Character accent menu for the "e" character]
- `false` => `repeat-character-while-key-held`: Holding a keyboard key down will repeat that key continuously, after a delay, until the key is released:
  [image: Key repeating animation]

## How to set `show-character-accents-menu` behaviour globally by default, but `repeat-character-while-key-held` behaviour per-application:

1. The `ApplePressAndHoldEnabled` `default` must be ***unset*** globally (rather than being set to `true` or `false`), with the following command:

```sh
defaults delete -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled    # Unset globally
```

2. The `ApplePressAndHoldEnabled` `default` must be ***set*** to `false` for each application for which you wish to set the `repeat-character-while-key-held` behaviour, with the following command:

```sh
defaults write "$APP_ID" ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Where `$APP_ID` is something like `com.jetbrains.intellij.ce` for "IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition".

**Paste this code in the terminal to set the `repeat-character-while-key-held` behaviour for all IntelliJ IDEs, but set `show-character-accents-menu` behviour globally:**

```sh
KEY='ApplePressAndHoldEnabled' \
&& defaults delete -g "$KEY" \
; echo \
&& APP_ID_PREFIX='com\.jetbrains\.' \
&& defaults read | egrep -o "${APP_ID_PREFIX}[^\"]+" | sort --unique \
| while read APP_ID; do
    echo "Setting \"repeat-character-while-key-held\" for application: '$APP_ID'..."
    defaults write "$APP_ID" "$KEY" -bool 'false'
done
```

## Checking global and app-specific set values of `ApplePressAndHoldEnabled`:

Values can be checked like this:

```sh
defaults read -g        ApplePressAndHoldEnabled    # Global
defaults read "$APP_ID" ApplePressAndHoldEnabled    # Per-application
```

**Paste this code in to the terminal to show the settings for `ApplePressAndHoldEnabled` globally and per-application:**

```sh
KEY='ApplePressAndHoldEnabled'
APP_ID_PREFIX='com\.jetbrains\.' \
&& echo \
&& printf "%-30s %-20s %-8s\n" \
    "Application" \
    "Type" \
    "Value" \
&& printf "%-30s %-20s %-8s\n" \
    "$(printf -- '-%.0s' {1..30})" \
    "$(printf -- '-%.0s' {1..16})" \
    "$(printf -- '-%.0s' {1..8})" \
&& (defaults read | egrep -o "${APP_ID_PREFIX}[^\"]+" | sort --unique && echo '-g') \
| while read APP_ID; do
    printf "%-30s %-20s %-4s\n" \
    "${APP_ID}" "\
    $(defaults read-type "${APP_ID}" "$KEY" 2> /dev/null || echo '(unset)')" \
    "$(defaults read "${APP_ID}" "$KEY" 2> /dev/null || echo '(unset)')"
done \
&& echo
```

Where this is the expected output:

```
Application                    Type                 Value
------------------------------ ----------------     --------
com.jetbrains.WebStorm         Type is boolean      0
com.jetbrains.intellij         Type is boolean      0
com.jetbrains.intellij.ce      Type is boolean      0
com.jetbrains.pycharm          Type is boolean      0
-g                             (unset)              (unset)
```

Comment: Would there be a way to disable for specific keys only e.g. for using vim in a foreign human language and disabling for `h`, `j`,`k`, `l` keys only?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the appropriate domain name by grepping the output of `defaults`:

```
defaults read | egrep -o 'com\.jetbrains\.\w+' | sort --unique
```

For IntelliJ Ultimate it gives me:

```
com.jetbrains.intellij
com.jetbrains.intellij-EAP
```

where the second one is for EAP builds of IntelliJ.

Comment: This just gives you the list of defaults that are set, not the list of defaults that are possible. Running that on my machine gives me a list of domains that have no effect.

Comment: This is the first mention I've seen of a fix for the EAP edition.  Been tearing my hair out over this, so thank you - particularly for the defaults tip.

Comment: See the canonical, complete solution to this problem, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70911250/14193

Answer (score 2):

As found in [this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/1408110/set-applepressandholdenabled-for-one-specific-application), it may be necessary to delete the global default before the application-specific default will be visible.

```
defaults delete -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled
```

After I did that and set an application-specific value for RubyMine...

```
defaults write com.jetbrains.rubymine ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true
```

...I could use IdeaVim in RubyMine and still use the press and hold accent dialog in all other applications.

Comment: See the canonical, complete solution to this problem, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70911250/14193

Answer (score 0):

Also, to find the needed "domain name" you can inspect the needed app like this:

1. locate the app (you can tap the app in the dock with ⌘ pressed to find it; it is most likely in `/Applications/` or `~/Applications/`)
2. tap the app with ⌃ pressed (or with right mouse click) and select "Show Package Content"
3. open Contents folder
4. open `Info.plist` file with any text editor (or just open preview with "Space")
5. find the key `CFBundleIdentifier` and its value enclosed in `<string>`

```
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.google.android.studio</string>
```

You are looking for the value (or "domain name" how it is called in context of this question).