# Key repeat in GitHub Codespaces

Tags: macos, github-codespaces

In the text editor of a GitHub Codespace...

- If I press-and-hold an arrow key on my keyboard, the key repeats. Perfect!
- If I press-and-hold the `j` key, only *one* `j` is inserted. Not perfect!

**How do I enable key repeat in the editor of a GitHub Codespaces for keys like `j`?**

(*If it makes a difference, I am using Google Chrome and MacOS.*)

Comment: If it makes a difference, my _real_ goal is to have the key repeats for the VIM Extension. However, even with the VIM disabled, `j` does not repeat. So I'm assuming that the lack of repeating `j` is unrelated to the VIM Extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In a macOS terminal, run one of the following:

- Enable globally:
  `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled 0`
- Enable only for Chrome:
  `defaults delete -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled`
  `defaults write "com.google.Chrome" ApplePressAndHoldEnabled 0`

2. Restart your browser.

You may be curious why you are setting `ApplePressAndHoldEnabled` to *false*. It is because setting it to *true* enables the show character accents menu. For more detail, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70911250/167920).

*HT: The IntelliJ IdeaVim plugin clued me into the existence of the `ApplePressAndHoldEnabled` setting.*